# Which graph plugin will suit best for such kind of value?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, charts, plotly

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]

Basically representing 
Low - lower quartile - mean - median - upper quartile values -These will be STATISTIC values.
and  value " YOu " will be the measuring parameter of individual performance

Need not be bar chart ,
Better visual representation is needed

" YOU " value needs to be highlighted in the graph.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try diffcharts of google
    https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/diffchart
(See the one at the bottom of this page)

Bar charts section-something like this small value to big, give your logic to 
    this and see if it conveys your visual idea.
    The one with a bar inside a bar from small to big will be good i think.
    Happy coding

Comment: I have updated the image ... its representing "YOU" value over other (Low- mean - median- high ) values

Comment: You can just give the graph input to show you, Low- mean - median- high in any order the data suggests, just that you can use diff-bar and line together if you want only a line for YOU thing else all the values will eb shown bars inside bars giving you the diff view